# Docker logs retrieval from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pagination, docker, fluentd

I want to store logs from Docker through Fluentd into MongoDB.
The setup is pretty straightforward, but what I'm struggling with is how to retrieve logs from MongoDB in the correct order with support for pagination.

The structure of a log document is

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  time: ISODate(...),
  log: "message"
}
```

The logs should be displayed from the newest to the oldest with support for pagination. Since the logs already arrive in the correct order - older logs are written before the newer logs. My approach is:

**First page** - `db.logs.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(10)` and save the last `_id`
**Next page** - `db.logs.find({_id: {$lt: lastIdFromPreviousPage).sort({_id: -1}).limit(10)`
etc.

The problem here is that [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) say:

> The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation
>   time is not strict within a single second.

This seems to be an issue - if I try to find all docs with `_id` lower than `lastIdFromPreviousPage`, it is not guaranteed that within a single second the documents are ordered in the order they were written. Some logs from the previous page may be included in the result even though they were already displayed on the previous page.

In MySQL if you order a result by an `auto_increment` field it is guaranteed that the results will be in the correct order, but what about MongoDB? What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1):

The cursor abstracts the pagination work for you. Check out [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html) for an example using batching, or just reading continuously from the cursor.

Comment: I probably should have stated that the logs will be displayed on a web page, my bad. In order to be able to use the same cursor, I would have to store/serialize it between individual requests which I don't think is supported based on the docs. Am I missing anything?